# Use a typed Bootstrap Modal variable in vue 3 sfc

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I am new to typescript and vue 3 js. I wrote a single-file-component and want to use a Bootstrap 5 modal. But my VSCode shows a error on my declared variable type. The error says:

> "Modal" refers to a value, but is used here as a type. Did you mean
> "type of modal"?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
   import { Modal } from "bootstrap";
   let modal: Modal = null;
   ...
</script>
```

I install via npm bootstrap and all JS type from bootstrap with

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap
```

Has anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0):

import type of modal only

```
   import type { Modal } from "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Negin Khademian points me to the right direction.
I made a second type import from bootstrap and use a alias to avoid collisions. Now it looks like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
   import type { Modal } from "bootstrap";
   import { Modal as BootstrapModal } from "bootstrap";
   let modal: Modal | null = null;
   ...
   modal = new BootstrapModal( document.getElementById( 'myModal' ) );
   ...
</script>
```